# Can we say inevitably important?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

In the following sentence I would like to mention that "**childhood is very important and its role is inevitable**". Is it clear to reduce this clause to **inevitably important**?

> The general view has been that childhood is inevitably important. We
> develop preferences as we grow up.

Comment: I don't think a role can be *inevitable*. A role is a function, position, attribute of something. It can't *happen*. Perhaps, you are looking for something like *unquestionably/undoubtedly/undeniably important, crucial, pivotal, critical.*

Comment: I don't even really understand what "childhood's role is inevitable" means.  "Childhood's role *(in doing what?)* is **unavoidable**"??  I think maybe *inevitable* is not the word you want, and that is making the question more confusing.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko So if the role of something cannot be inevitable, then what kind of things can be inevitable. Can I say the role is irrefutable and the result is inevitable?